# Checking integrity of ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Book` model that stores the authors as a `ManyToManyField` to `Person` through table `Author`. The intermediate `Author` table exists because it adds the `order` property:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Author')

class Author(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

What I want is to verify that, for a given book, `order` starts with 1 and is contiguous. Where can I do this check? I can't do it in `Book.save()`, because first you need to save the book, then you add authors to it (that's how `ManyToManyField`s work AFAIU). I can't do it in `Author.save()`, because it is normal that there is temporary loss of integrity (e.g. if there are 4 authors, I delete author with order=3, then I update the last author setting order=3; there is loss of integrity between the two steps).

I guess the integrity should be checked on commit. Is there any standard or recommended practice for doing this?

Comment: This article may offer a solution: http://schinckel.net/2012/02/06/pre-validating-many-to-many-fields./

Comment: No, that solution doesn't work. When there's an intermediary model, `m2m_changed` doesn't fire (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13757). (And if it did, it wouldn't be much use if it was triggered once for each row added, which it probably would.)